# What is the meaning of 'N-SING' in the Collins COBUILD dictionary?

Tags: parts-of-speech

N-SING represents singular noun according to the explanation in the Collins COBUILD dictionary. Can I interpret it as a noun that is countable but unable to be used in plural form and only able to be used in singular form?

[image]

Comment: as you say, nouns countable in concept but used only in the singular.

Comment: @MingLu _Lottery_ is countable and _can_ be used in the plural ("lotteries").  It is difficult to understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3):

An `n-sing` is the form of the noun that is used to refer to one person or thing (and differs from the plural): literally NOUN, SINGULAR.

> The singular of Inuit is Inuk

Inuk would be an `n-sing`.

[Source](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/singular%20[grammar])

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that is not what I'm asking. I'm asking what the meaning of 'N-SING' in the Collins COBUILD dictionary is!!!

Comment: The answer did give you the information: "a noun used to refer to one person or thing". I have added the literal expansion: N(OUN) SING(ULAR)

Comment: @MingLu - Your copy of Collins COBUILD contains an entry in which the terminology is explained. Have you read it?

Comment: I use dictionaries from offline resources with goldendict so that I don't have the file explaining the terminology. Can you help me find the entry which explains the terminology? I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**N-SING**

A **singular noun** is always singular, and needs a determiner, e.g. … to damage the ***environment*** … He looks the ***epitome*** of personal and professional contentment.

Collins Cobuild. COBUILD Advanced Learner’s Dictionary KINDLE-ONLY EDITION (Kindle Locations 404-406). HarperCollins Publishers. Kindle Edition.